# Expansion of $1/\log\left(\dfrac{f(a)^2 - f(x)^2}{f(a)^2 + f(x)^2}\right)$ around $a$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

I want to know what's the order of the second leading term in the expansion of
$1/\log\left(\dfrac{f(a)^2 - f(x)^2}{f(a)^2 + f(x)^2}\right)$ around $a$. For now, I have:
$$1/\log\left(\dfrac{f(a)^2 - f(x)^2}{f(a)^2 + f(x)^2}\right) = \dfrac{1}{\log(f(a) - f(x))+ \log(f(a) + f(x)) - \log(f(a)^2 + f(x)^2)}$$
Close to $a$, we find:

$$1/\log\left(\dfrac{f(a)^2 - f(x)^2}{f(a)^2 + f(x)^2}\right) \sim \dfrac{1}{\log(f(a) - f(x))-\log(a)}$$

We also have: $f(a) - f(x) \sim (a - x)f'(a) - \dfrac{1}{2}(a - x)^2f''(x)$. Putting this in the log gives us:

$$\log(f(a) -f(x)) \sim \log((a - x)f'(a)) - \dfrac{(a - x)f''(a)}{2f'(a)}$$

Finaly we have:
$$1/\log\left(\dfrac{f(a)^2 - f(x)^2}{f(a)^2 + f(x)^2}\right) \sim \dfrac{1}{\log((a - x)f'(a)/f(a)) - \dfrac{(a - x)f''(a)}{2f'(a)}}$$

Now, if we expand that in a sum of terms, clearly, the first leading term is of order $1/\log(a - x)$ but what is the order of the second term? Something like $(a - x)$ (at least that's what mathematica is giving me...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to have any order is you use steps
Expand $f(x)$ as a series around $x=a$ and use long division
$$A=\dfrac{f(a)^2 - f(x)^2}{f(a)^2 + f(x)^2}=$$
$$-\frac{ f'(a)}{f(a)}(x-a)+\frac{ \left(f'(a)^2-f(a)
   f''(a)\right)}{2 f(a)^2}(x-a)^2+O\left((x-a)^3\right)$$

$$\log(A)=\log \left(-\frac{(x-a) f'(a)}{f(a)}\right)+\frac{(x-a)
   \left(f(a) f''(a)-f'(a)^2\right)}{2 f(a)
   f'(a)}+O\left((x-a)^2\right)$$ Long division again
$$\frac 1 {\log(A)}=\frac{1}{\log \left(-\frac{(x-a) f'(a)}{f(a)}\right)} \,\left(1+\frac 12 B +O\left((x-a)^2\right) \right)$$ where
$$B=\frac{ f'(a)^2-f(a) f''(a)}{ f(a) f'(a) \log
   \left(-\frac{(x-a) f'(a)}{f(a)}\right)}\,\,(x-a)$$